# Web visitor data storing without database/server

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I have a research project which is focusing on understanding user's curiosity and connecting to Free WIFI including remote areas where internet is poor here.

To do this, we developed simple webpages with the first as a Visitor's form where we need a user/visitor to enter their data and let it be retrieved, saved or viewed later as user logs. We want to do this by simply having a Router and a Flash disk where the webfiles and data storing system will be...No server!

Is this very possible with Javascript, xml and or any other languages anyone has ever done this? That is except Javascript's LocalStorage which in this say, the user will be the one to have his/her own data.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual request really. I agree a relational DB would be the best choice. Of course you can just save to text file (xml or not) and later use that file in Excel or so. That would be my choice.

Comment: Well Thanks @User2040543 and you have any script you can share on that?

Comment: Sorry no, but I agree with the other poster that a web server on the computer (www or not) would  make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably store data with LocalStorage, and allow user to save data by exporting a .JSON or .CSV or something like that.

You can give the user a file to download by doing a window.open() on a Data URI containing the text of the JSON or CSV:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs